# Matlab: Make 9 rows of the same value without storing all 9 values

Tags: matlab

I need to create an array of 1e7 x 9 values. All rows are different but all columns are replicas of the first row:

```
n=1e7; %simulations
t=1:8; %contacts
lambdaU=repmat(rand(n,1),1,length(t)+1) %<<<<<<<Here 

CalcTimU=zeros(n,length(t)+1);

%I then do:
for j=1:n %for each simulation (row)
    for i=2:length(t)+1 % for each column

    CalcTimU(j,i)=CalcTimU(j,i-1)+lambdaU(j,i).*(10-CalcTimU(j,i-1));


    end 
end
```

This seems to be very wasteful. Is there any way of reducing the amount of storage?

Comment: What is your expected output? Please explain with a small sample example

Comment: You only read `lambdaU(j,1)` in this code, what do you need the other columns for?

Comment: I've made it now depend on I and j.

Comment: But the example still doesn't make sense: you can replace `lambdaU(j,i)` with `lambdaU(j,1)` and get exactly the same output. Now you're again not needing those additional columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can even vectorize the *j* loop:

```
n=1500; %simulations
t=1:8; %contacts

lvec = rand(n,1);
lambdaU=repmat(lvec,1,length(t)+1); %<<<<<<<Here 

CalcTimU=zeros(n,length(t)+1);

tic
%I then do:
for j=1:n %for each simulation (row)
    for i=2:length(t)+1 % for each column
    CalcTimU(j,i)=CalcTimU(j,i-1)+lambdaU(j,i).*(10-CalcTimU(j,i-1));
    end 
end
toc

% Vectorized:
tic
CalcTimU2=zeros(n,length(t)+1);
for i=2:length(t)+1
    CalcTimU2(:,i) = CalcTimU2(:,i-1)+lvec.*(10-CalcTimU2(:,i-1));
end
toc

isequal(CalcTimU,CalcTimU2)
```

And the results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.220032 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.00030899 seconds.
ans = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't realise you could vectorise inside for loops! Saves loads of time too!